# SharePoint appredirect.aspx redirects with POST

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, mvc

I have a provider-hosted app built with MVC deployed in SharePoint Online.  I have a controller, `Tasks`, and an action, `Details`.  If I navigate to the details page for a particular task (`/Tasks/Details?taskId=3`) from either a bookmark or saved link for the first time, it goes to the host site, then redirects to the app, as it should.  However, as you can see in the following picture, what starts as a GET request becomes a POST request after the redirect.

[image]

Has `appredirect.aspx` always redirected with a POST?

Currently the only way I can load the page is if I allow POST requests.  Is this the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the SharePoint app model then yes, you must allow posts.  SharePoint sends authorization & authentication data to your app via post.  Your app needs that data to generate a client context.

Take a look at the tokenhelper.cs file and/or the landing page code behind & you should see the post data processing

Comment: I just found this [link](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2015/07/errors-in-sharepoint-apps-add-ins.html), which mirrors what you said.  Thanks for the affirmation.